# Запись списка строкой в Excel python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

У меня есть список values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Мне нужно его записать строкой (то есть в ячейки A1, B1, C1, D1, E1) в excel. Выходило лишь записать в столбец. Список может быть разной длины. Может, кто знает, как это сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: Транспонируйте DataFrame и запишите его excel.

Comment: @Сергей Кох   Зачем? Какой DataFrame надо "транспонировать", если у ТС есть просто список?

Answer (score 0):

```
import  openpyxl as ox
wb=ox.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i, statN in enumerate(data): 
    ws.cell(row=1, column=i+1).value = statN 
wb.save('some.xlsx')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вообще-то рекомендую начинать изучение программирования с чтения элементарных учебников.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dft = df.T
dft.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```